# View is Clipping its Content error

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

I'm using Xcode 4.6. In a window I keep getting this "view is clipping its content" error and when I click on it, the XIB editor highlights a label. What is this error trying to tell me and how to I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

First, clicking on the text "View is clipping..." will select the control that has the issue. it happens when you resize a text field too small for the inner text field cell to fit in. enlarging the control makes warning disappear. you can also select the inner cell and go to size inspector to see if there are options to make it smaller to match your desired overall size.

Comment: Well, now with xcode 12.4 clicking on the warning does nothing and i've got a large storyboard and no idea how to find the culprit :(

Answer (score 1):

You have a carriage return / newline at the end of the text in your label. That empty line is part of the "content" which is larger than the "view". Get rid of your extra newline and you'll take care of this.

Answer (score -1):

It's telling you that your constraints hasn't been set up correctly. You can resolve the by clicking on the view in question, then clicking on the small icon at the bottom and choose: "***Reset to suggested constraints***"

[image]

Or you could click on the little small orange (or red) arrow in your Document Outline (the list to the left of your view that shows all views), then click on ***Resolve Issue***

Comment: Are you sure this applies to Xcode 4.6? I don't see "Resolve issue" and I only see 3 buttons in the bottom right

Comment: Ah no, that's not the case in Xcode 4.6. That's new in Xcode 5. Have a look here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881 You'll most likely going to find an answer there.

Comment: Well it's pretty much the same principle. But have a look att the session videos: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/ Especially "Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X", "Auto Layout by Example" and "Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout"